# Python: Sorting dictionary based on value (list)

Tags: python

I have dictionary which has `{key : []}` format. I need to prepare a list sorted based on the length of the value (length of the list). What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: A list of what? The values sorted by length?

Comment: Duplicate [sorting a list of dictionary values by date in python][1]?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652291/sorting-a-list-of-dictionary-values-by-date-in-python?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for the values sorted by length, and assuming dict `d`:

```
lists_by_length = sorted(d.values(), key=len)
```

Also see [Sort a Python dictionary by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/python-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Comment: the list consists of objects from `Vertex` class and the following errors are occured `AttributeError: Vertex instance has no attribute '__len__'`

Comment: The the values aren't naive python `list`s, or objects that implement `__len__`. How do you extract the `Vertex` object's length?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I added a global function to process the vertex class.